KrakenD response format in krakenD [community edition]
I'm facing issues formatting reponses in krakenD.


   "@comment": "Verify OTP and Sign Access Token and Refresh Token",
   "endpoint": "/auth/login-with-mobile/verify",
   "method": "POST",
   "backend": [
     {
       "encoding": "no-op",
       "url_pattern": "/v1/auth/login-with-mobile/verify"
     }
   ],
   "extra_config": {
     "auth/signer": {
       "alg": "HS256",
       "kid": "sim2",
       "keys_to_sign": ["access_token", "refresh_token"],
       "jwk_url": "http://mobipay-backend-service:4000/symmetric.json",
       "disable_jwk_security": true
     }
   }
 },




This is the configuration I'm using in krakenD to connect my nestjs backend.
Nestjs backend return this response for validation error.
{
    "message": [
        "phone must be a valid phone number",
        "otp should not be empty"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "statusCode": 400
}

But for this response, krakenD shows Could not get a response. Just return a status code 401 in Postman despite any status code return from the backend.

if i use
"auth/validator": {
          "alg": "HS256",
          "roles_key": "roles",
          "roles": [],
          "jwk_url": "http://mobipay-backend-service:4000/symmetric.json",
          "disable_jwk_security": true
        }
}




Config krakenD just returns a status code with an empty body. How can I modify that response body?
